# excel formula to locate a set of number in parentheses

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I would like to know if there is a formula in excel or macro code to locate a set of numbers in every row of column B and put that set of numbers in column C? Something like a text to column...

[image: Just locate the numbers within the parentheses and add them to column C]

Comment: Examine `MID()` and `FIND()` --> `=MID(B2,FIND("(",B2)+1,FIND(")",B2)-FIND("(",B2)-1)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This formula will find anything between the first set of parentheses no matter how many characters exist between the parentheses (good in case the number of characters might be variable)

```
=MID(B1,(FIND("(",B1)+1),FIND(")",B1)-FIND("(",B1)-1)
```

You can use the Text to Column feature to separate the numbers out from within the parentheses.  Just run it twice on the column, using the left then right parentheses as the delimiter of the column.  You will end up with 3 columns: Data before the left parentheses, the numerical data you want, and data after the right parentheses.

Comment: FWIW, I wrote this independently before you amended your comment to include almost exactly the same formula... great minds think alike? ;)

Comment: Guys sorry for posting the question without the attempt... I actually was trying to record a macro that would do the text to column but no luck there at all... just had another question though... The answer worked perfectly fine but I came across this one issue where in some rows the first set of parentheses contains (On Leave) or (Terminated) and then the actual numbers I need (345543)... How could I avoid this?

Comment: @William There's not a simple way to do that since it's only happening on *some* lines.  You can certainly do it in code, but it's not just a 1-2 line request, so beyond scope here. You could add a 2nd col that uses `FIND` starting after the 1st close paren to get the numbers from the 2nd parens, then make a 3rd column that checks `ISNUMBER` on the 1st col and if it fails, uses the 2nd col.  3 sets of parens in one row would break this way too, but in code you could be more sure...

Comment: Thanks for the advise here I will try it code better and will post an answer of what I find...

Answer (score 2):

In another column enter:

```
=MID(B1,FIND("(",B1)+1,6)
```

and copy down

Comment: wouldn't work if the number was longer than 6 characters and/or shorted than 6 would return unnecessary junk